# Oracle SQL Developer crash

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

Started SQL Developer, tried to connect to my server, got:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

C:\Oracle12\product\12.2.0\client_2\64bit\ocijdbc12.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Vendor code 0
```

How do I fix this?  Note that I'm running on Win7-64 Sp1.  The error message is wrong about the platform I think.

Comment: Download 32 bit Java 8 JDK. Download SQL Developer from oracle.com/sqldeveloper. Install Java. Extract SQLDev from zip. Run the EXE

Comment: thanks! I'll do that

Comment: Found a simpler workaround:  Removed the refs to the 64-bit client from PATH